# Android web app rendering font/type strangely (shifting up)

Tags: android, css, web-applications, mobile, font-face

I'm currently taking a mobile web app from the design stages to the development stages. During this process, I'm importing a custom font family that will be used in the interface, via @font-face. I tried using strictly OTF before and I was getting a strange font rendering issue where all type is being shifted upwards by about 4px (2px if not high-density). iOS is rendering it properly and keeping it in the right place, as is the desktop experience.

Figuring it was a font rendering issue, I went back and added EOT, WOFF, TFF, and SVG to my @font-face properties. Still, same issue persisted.

Is there any known reason why my Android experience is shifting my type upwards?

Comment: Could you include some markup snippets, or possibly even a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It would make it easier for others to try it out.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tested this locally using sans-serif, serif, Google web-font, localized Google web-font font-face (using a TTF off their site), and my custom font-face.

It seems the typeface I am trying to use is giving me the problem and was not created with baseline considerations. I will have to explore alternative typefaces.

I've uploaded a jsFiddle but the font I am trying to use isn't in the CSS, because it's a paid font and I can't release it. For those that may encounter this issue in the future, feel free to tweak it to test on your devices.

http://jsfiddle.net/9zcKe